# What is the replacement for contentType attribute of deprecated mule-transport-http?

Tags: mule, mule-esb

Switching from an [old-fashioned](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.9/deprecated-http-transport-reference) `mule-transport-http` to `mule-module-http`.

In my XML I had the following inbound endpoint:

```
<http:inbound-endpoint contentType="text/xml" exchange-pattern="request-response" host="0.0.0.0" port=1337 path="/">
```

There is no similar attribute in a modern `<http:listener>` (see [comparison table](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.9/migrating-to-the-new-http-connector#inbound-endpoint-vs-listener)). How is it supposed to replace this setting?

Comment: What was the use for that attribute within an inbound-endpoint? There nothing like that in the new module because all server paths allow any content type.

Comment: @afelisatti do not know actually. I suppose it was used to reject requests with not matched or missing Content-Type. Need to check.

Comment: @afelisatti just checked. To my surprise it does not reject `application/xml` request on `application/json` inbound http endpoint. It will set invocation property for `Content-Type` key to `application/json` value regardless what type I set in actual request header.

Answer (score 0):

I did some tests with my old Mule 3.5.0 project.

When you set `contentType` attribute for deprecated `http:inbound-endpoint` it does not reject requests with other or missing `Content-Type` header.
It also does not set it as a value for response header.
BUT I noticed that it does set an invocation property (variable) `Content-Type` (can be checked with `message.getInvocationPropertyNames()`).
So the equivalent will be:

```
<http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration"
path="somePath"/>
<set-variable variableName="Content-Type" value="text/xml"/>
```

I do not see any reason to leave this variable if it is not used somehow (at least I did not notice it's usage)